# How to create Presigned put url and use environment variable to set Bucket and Key

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3

I'm using the following code to create a presigned put url:

```
svc := s3.New(nil)
req, _ := svc.PutObjectRequest(&s3.PutObjectInput{
    Bucket: aws.String("myBucket"),
    Key:    aws.String("myKey"),
})
str, err := req.Presign(15 * time.Minute)

log.Println("The URL is:", str, " err:", err)
```

But I would like to get the configuration from a environment variable:

```
CONFIGURATIONS={ "Bucket": "myBucket", "Key": "myKey" }
```

I have just two weeks of Golang, and I have mainly a background in Node.js, so, I'm sorry if this question is very basic.

To better illustrate, I'm trying to do this... but in Go:

```
const CONFIGURATIONS = JSON.parse(process.env.CONFIGURATIONS)

const S3 = new AWS.S3()
S3.generatePresignedUrl('putObject', CONFIGURATIONS, callback...)
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you need to retrieve the bucket and key name from env variables. This is pretty easy to do in go. The `os` package has a `GetEnv` function for that.

Assuming your env variables are called `AWS_BUCKET` and `AWS_KEY` this is the way to get the values:

```
bucketName := Getenv("AWS_BUCKET")
key := Getenv("AWS_KEY")
```

You can check the package docs [here](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Getenv).